# how to get href value in Server side when click the anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, server-side

I have a table that contain anchor tag in each row, when click the anchor link i get href value using jquery and bind the href value in hidden field, at the same time i want to pass the hidden field value in server side..!

how to pass the hidden field value when click the anchor tag is this possible..?
or suggest some other way

Comment: When you click the anchor link and use jquery to bind href in hidden field, also use an ajax GET or POST to send that href to server: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp Good luck!

Comment: Please show us the logic you have so far.  Also it's unclear if clicking the link is going to submit some form, or if you are allowing it to do a page transition, or what.

Comment: I used ajax Post metod to send href value to server side, its working thanks buddy @Chris

Comment: OK, Great job!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get href value using jquery like

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.info_link').click(function () {
                        var href = $(this).attr('href');
                        getHREFValue(href);
                    });
                });
```

then using Ajax to pass the href value to server side

```
                function getHREFValue(data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{'HrefValue':'" + data + "'}",
                        url: "./List.aspx/Insert",
                        success: function (Record) {

                            if (Record.d == true) {
                                console.log("Success");
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Failure");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
```